# Geth not syncing to last block

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

i have been trying to run a node in a virtual machine. Im using Ubuntu 16.04 and have already installed Geth to it. Im running it with geth --rpc --cache=1024 --verbosity 5. When i attach to the console and send the eth.syncing command i get this information:

```
{
  currentBlock: 4081498,
  highestBlock: 4081655,
  knownStates: 747286,
  pulledStates: 730115,
  startingBlock: 4067468
}
```

I cant get it to sync to the last block, please dont tell me to delete de blockchain and start again because i have already done it like 5 times and i always get stucked. Have already lost 2 weeks in syncing time.

What is wrong with my node?

My node is listed in the ethstats panel as "ArgenPool"